# Recalculation of columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, where-clause, calculated-columns

Good day. Don't know if already asked, I looked but didn't find anything, I am not even sure "recalculation is the correct term.

I have a query in which one of the columns is composed of a calculus of others, and is assigned an alias:

```
SELECT col1 LIKE CONCAT(col2,"some_key%") as pivot1 ... others columns ... 
WHERE col1 LIKE CONCAT(col2,"some_key%") = 1
```

I cannot use `HAVING` at the moment for current db handler layer limit.
The question is, will the calculus column `col1 LIKE CONCAT(col2,"some_key")` be performed twice, in the select and where parts, with double resources loss? There are other columns calculated as alias and then checked in the where clause, in a big table, so performance is of relevance.

If so, we could start some editing on the old inherited db handler, otherwise we would opt to continue using it as is, for the moment, not spending time in modernizing it yet.

Thanks in advance for any question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do it twice. The `WHERE` clause implies that the value of that expression will always be 1, so you can just hard-code it into the `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT 1 as pivot1, ...
FROM ...
WHERE col1 LIKE CONCAT(col2,"some_key%")
```

You also don't need `= 1` when testing the result of a comparison operator. It can simply be used as a boolean expression by itself.

I believe that MySQL does repeat the calculation. I did the following test:

```
select sum(username like '%x') from t_users where username like '%x' or 1=1;

select sum(1) from t_users where username like '%x' or 1=1;
```

The first query took about 12% longer than the second.

Note that if you do repeat the expression in the `SELECT` clause, it won't be performed twice on all rows in the table. It will only be performed twice on the rows in the result set that's chosen by the `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses. So it may not be as severe a performance hit as you expect. For example, I tested:

```
select sum(username like '%z') from t_users where username like  '%z' ;

select sum(1) from t_users where username like '%z';
```

These took about the same amount of time, because the `WHERE` clause reduced the result set to about 1% of the table.

Comment: Unless the OP is only showing us part of the full query.  There may be an `OR` later on.

Comment: There are some ORs in the where clause, almost all including calculations, and several joins. Also I need the alias in the select to refer them later in the server side code. The answer is very good asd detailed, thank you! I know about = 1, just showed for code clarity, but +1 for 1 as pivot1... Didn't know about it!